# Spring 4 @DateTimeFormat with Java 8 doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, hibernate-validator

Well, I have a property of type `java.time.LocalDate`, let's call it `birthDate`, and it's annotated with `@DateTimeFormat`:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate birthDate;
// getters and setters
```

on `jsp` page:

```
<tr>
    <td><mvc:label path="birthDate">Birth Date</mvc:label></td>
    <td><mvc:input path="birthDate" cssErrorClass="field-error"/></td>
    <td><mvc:errors path="birthDate" /></td>
</tr>
```

So I what I expect from that:

1. HTML5 rendering of the field, i.e. `<input type="date" />`
2. Validation.

Basically if I had html5 date input, I would already have validation.
All I have now is just `<input type="text" />` and if the date is malformed I got a bunch of exceptions on the page. So I am really confused, because there's cute pictures of html5 inputs on the internet while I got nothing.
So the question is how do I achieve all of that?

**UPD**
Seems like Spring 4 doesn't provide full support of `LocalDate` *yet* (according to Mert Caliskan's book). But still, if someone could come up with nice solution that would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Note that the HTML date/time input types have wildly different support on different browsers, so that might be part of it.

Comment: Yeah I thought of it, but where [this](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/06/spring-4-datetimeformat-with-java-8.html) come from? Sure I have workarounds but this is really confusing.

Comment: @chrylis Also I figured out that despite of different formats of the actual rendered input, the actual data is in one format: `yyyy-mm-dd`(e.g. in `value` attribute). [Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqw4r58k/)

Comment: First of all decide if this is a browser issue or your Java code issue. Try to inspect the request sent by the browser and see exactly what it sends.